# How do I select all rows for those persons who have only zero contributions for every entry

Tags: sql, select, row

```
Here is a example of the table I want to query:

Contribution_Table
ID     LASTNAME   FIRSTNAME   CONTRIBUTION   YEAR
392    Bob        Sully       0.00           2012
392    Bob        Sully       0.00           2013
392    Bob        Sully       0.00           2014
465    John       Greene      0.00           2012 
465    John       Greene      5.60           2013
465    John       Greene      0.00           2014
892    Jane       Crain       0.00           2012
892    Jane       Crain       0.00           2013
892    Jane       Crain       0.00           2014

I want as a result only a list containing those individuals
who have never made a contribution, like so:

ID     LASTNAME   FIRSTNAME   CONTRIBUTION   YEAR
392    Bob        Sully       0.00           2012
392    Bob        Sully       0.00           2013
392    Bob        Sully       0.00           2014
892    Jane       Crain       0.00           2012
892    Jane       Crain       0.00           2013
892    Jane       Crain       0.00           2014
```

Notice that John Greene is excluded because he made 
a contribution in 2013, even though he had zero
contributions in 2012 and 2014. Also notice
that the resultant list shows each year that a person
has zero dues -- in that it doesn't sum or group the 
resultant individuals, which is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a query as such

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Contribution_Table

WHERE CONTRIBUTION=0
AND ID NOT IN
    (SELECT ID FROM Contribution_Table WHERE CONTRIBUTION > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER: IDK if using CTE here is overkill. But it works**

```
with cte as 
(
  select ID, SUM(CONTRIBUTION) as csum from tab group by ID
)
select * from tab where tab.id in (select cte.id from cte where cte.csum = 0)
```

This will work. Heres the working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/86ef2/1)